# Unable to set image path in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am working on a react native project. 
In this I want to get image file from image so that I can send it in formdata. My image is stored in assets folder inside my project structure.I have tried but unable to get it done. I also tried to convert it into base64 by the help of RN-fetch-blob.

Below is the code I used:

```
 RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile('../assets/img/user.png', 'base64')
     .then((data) => {
        console.log("base 64 string is > ", data);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error >", error)
    })
```

But It is unable to read from the local folder. Please help

Comment: I tried to find information about the issue and found this: `4. Only the images that are actually used will be packaged into your app.` Which means you will have to add an array to your app where all the pre-packaged images are `require`d, otherwise they won't be accessible apparently.

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker

Comment: @ChrisG How can I do this, can you please elaborate.

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh I have used it for interaction with Camera and gallery but unable to use it for the local folder images